# Order Confirmation Email Not Sending Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email, cron, order-email

New order confirmation emails are not being sent out when an order is processed.

If I add a comment to the order and click 'notify customer by email' that will send the update to your order notification, but if I click the 'Send Sales Email' but

The contact us form will also send without any issue.

Even though the back-end says: **Order # 000000183** (The order confirmation email was sent)
There is most definitely no order confirmation being sent out.

- The Cron is running as intended
- I don't seem to be receiving any errors in the logs related to the issue at hand.
- I attempted to temporarily fix the issue by utilising the third-party [Magento2-GmailSMTP-App](https://github.com/magepal/magento2-gmailsmtpapp) but this didn't make any difference.
- Emails can definitely be sent from the external SMTP server.
- Payment methods currently being used are PayPal and Finance, the results is the same for both processes.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Facing same issue. Mostly it deals with Cron Job & SMTP Server.

Comment: Disable asynchronous sending of emails: `Sales -> Emails -> General -> Asynchronous sending`

Comment: Did you reach to solution?

Comment: Andy, please update if you found a sollution. I;m struggeling for 3 weeks now and still no sollution....

Comment: please check my answer https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/212031/49821