# Magento 2 - Order # 000000094 (The order confirmation email is not sent) - Order Placed Successfully but confirmation email is not sent

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am facing this issue many times. when i place any order from front-end side,  the order placing successfully and it's show order number. but when i check this order on my back-end admin it show this (The order confirmation email is not sent) message.  and nothing on my mail box. i send this order mail manually pressing "send email"  button.

- Other mails are working fine(REGISTRATION,SUBSCRIPTIONS AND OTHER ORDER STATUS MAIL ) and as a time. but just only order confirmation email is not working.

[image]

is that any setting from back-end to solved this issue?

Comment: This magento setup is in ur local server?

Comment: Have u check magento cron. If not then you should add cron.sh to cronjob

Comment: no it's not in local. and other mail working fine, so no issue on cron.

Comment: how to add cron.sh to cron?

Comment: Any updates? I'm facing the same and struggeling to find a sollution for 3 weeks now

Comment: Any update? I am also facing this issue.

Comment: Are you using online payment method?

Comment: @AISTechnolabs Any update? I am also facing this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had same issue. 
I found below thing in code.

```
$order->setCanSendNewEmailFlag(false);
```

I was using one custom payment method, That payment method had stopped order email to be sent with above line of code. I removed that and emails are working fine for me. above code I found on **BeforeOrderPlaceObserver**

so if you are facing same issue you should check once for all custom payment method that you are using that might be preventing order emails to be sent.

Comment: Yes, custom payment method causing problem.

Answer (score 0):

Set up email settings for your web server;

Verify that you can send and receive email using php function "mail";

```
Check Stores->Configuration-> Advanced->System->Mail Sending Settings. Email Communication is enabled.
```

`Check Stores->Configuration-> Sales->Sales Emails->Order` . Enabled is "Yes".

Comment: thanks Sir, But i already follow this steps.